# Static files in ASP.NET Core works locally but not once published to Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm building an ASP.NET Core application and need to serve up a few small static files (eventually they'll probably move to a CDN but that's later).  All the docs tell you to put static files in the `public` folder which is what I did:

[image]

Locally, when I run the server, it works:

[image]

However, when I publish the site to Azure, the page isn't found (it appears to use the React routing or something):

[image]

I can confirm the file actually gets published and exists on Azure at `/wwwroot/ClientApp/build/Specs/api.yaml` so it's not any sort of publishing issue:

[image]

I haven't touched the Startup.cs file or web.config, everything should be default.  I've also tried other static files, like `.htm` and `.txt` to make sure it's nothing to do with the file extension, but same issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: Normally it should not work in local folder also. The file in server must be at /home/site/wwwroot/wwwroot/Specs/api.yaml, for linux app service wwwroot repeats two times.

Comment: Which the type of  app service you use? Windows or Linux?

Comment: @JimXu This is using Windows

Comment: OK. I will do some research